# Skype breaks when I remove headphone jack

Tags: skype, speakers

I have my laptop connected to my speakers via a headphone jack. Every time I receive a skype call I pull out the headphone jack (or the sound's too echoey), but then skype is unable to use the laptop's built-in speakers unless I restart skype.

Does anyone else have this problem, and is it likely to be a hardware, skype or driver problem?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What version of the Skype software?

Comment: "plug" rather than "jack" - a "jack" is what you plug the "plug" into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Skype, go to Tools, Options, Audio Settings. In there should be the setting you need to fix your Skype issue. Possible the default speaker setting may be set incorrectly.

-Good Luck